# What is Datameer & How it is related to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am pretty new to Datameer. I just want to Know that

1. What is Datameer?
2. How Datameer is related to Hadoop?
3. How Git is used with Datameer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Website :https://www.datameer.com/product/product-overview/

What is Datameer?

From a usage point of view it is a Rapid Data Ingestion and Visualization tool. Primarily focused towards business users who have been using MS xls for data analysis and charting.

How Datameer is related to Hadoop?

Datameer can sit on top of hadoop ecosystem. Under such a set up jobs (a set of data processing activities to achieve something i.e. quiet often you would feel like you are writing excel formulas) in datameer are passed down to Resource Manager for execution as hadoop jobs (which in turn would be Map/Reduce Tasks.)

Datameer has a easy to use GUI on top of Hadoop and also helps provides ease of scheduling.

How Git is used with Datameer?

https://github.com/Datameer-Inc

I do not completely understand this question. 
If you are thinking in context of how open source tools have repositories in Git from which installation files and patches are pulled down and also at times new code is pushed and integrated then most likely Datameer software package does not work this way.

Try posting your query in the Datameer Community Page with a more exact question on Git that you want clarity on.

https://datameer.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts